# Mutexes inside if condition

Tags: c++, loops, mutex

I have a problem with mutexes...

This is the general structure of my code:

```
#include <mutex>
std::mutex m;

While(1){
    m.lock();
    if(global_variable1==1){
        //CODE GOES HERE
        if (err==error::eof){
            cout<<"error!"<<endl;
            //should I put a m.unlock() here??
            continue;
        }
        int something=1;
        global_variable2=something;
    }
    m.unlock();
    usleep(100000);

}
```

Basically, I want to change global variable safely, so I think I need to use mutexes. I should only unlock the mutex after that "if(global_variable1==1)" function, but if there is an error, the mutex won't be unlocked.. Can I unlock it before the "continue"? Or is this going mess up with anything else? Can having two unlocks for the same mutex.lock() have a undesired behaviour?

Comment: you must guarentee `unlock();` call but if you put it before `continue;` can you be sure that `unlock();` will be called eventually?

Comment: yes. The lock is called before the first `if`. There are only two ways out: that `if(error)` and the end of the first `if`. there's an unlock after the first if. The question is: should I have the one that is commented as well?

Comment: It seems you should.Otherwise there will be and unlocked mutex when error occured after `continue` by-passes bottom `unlock()`

Comment: thanks for your reply ! I was able to solve it already

Answer (score 1):

This is why C++ has separate lock and mutex classes: a lock is a handy RAII class that will make sure that your mutex gets unlocked even when exceptions are thrown or some other idiot programmer adds a new `return`/`break`/`continue` into the program. Here's how this program works with `std::unique_lock`:

```
#include <mutex>
std::mutex m;

While(1){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if(global_variable1==1){
        //CODE GOES HERE
        if (err==error::eof){
            cout<<"error!"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        int something=1;
        global_variable2=something;
    }
    lock.unlock();

    usleep(100000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** lock/unlock mutexes manually! Instead use a guard, e.g., `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`: the guard will acquire a lock upon construction an release it upon destruction. To limit the time the lock is held, just use a block:

```
while (true) {
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> cerberos(m);
        // ...
    }
    sleep(n);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood...
I have multiple threads and so, I wanted to use mutexes to prevent them to access global variables at the same time.
If I use `lock_guard`, how do I know when its destruction happens, if I'm using it inside an infinite loop?

Comment: @Carollour: objects are destroyed when the scope they live in is exited, independent on how it is exited. putting a block around the section of code which needs to synchronize it accesses and using the guard inside neatly acquires/releases the lock at appropriate times.